# How to send event data as part of form request in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the code below which works fine by posting request to backend via ajax/jquery.

**What I want to accomplished:**

Now I want to get variable data when form input is focused and keypressed and send them as part of the request via ajax jquery
such that the **datasend** variable will look something like

```
var datasend = "myname="+ myname + "&focu=" + focu + "&pres=" + pres;
```

here is the script showing how I can successfully post data to via ajax/jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#create').click(function(){
var myname= $('#myname').val();     
var datasend = "myname="+ myname;
        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'save.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg){
                // print result
                            alert('success');
            }
            });
    })
});
</script>
```

Here is the form inputs

```
<input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" value="haco" />
<input type='text' id="myfocus" value="">
<input type='text' id="mypress" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit " id="create" />
```

below is how I can successfully check form input **focus** and **keypress**.

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
if ($('#myfocus').is(':focus')) {
alert('am focused');
var focu='am focused';
  }
});

 $('#mypress').keyup(function(){
  alert('am pressed');
var pres= 'am pressed';

});
```

Any idea on how i can achieve that requested above. Is there any work around or suggestions?

Comment: Can you give me a better explanation about what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there already, you just need to get the data in locations accessible to your POST request.  You can determine focus right before the AJAX call, to store a keypress you'd need to create a global variable.

```
var press = false;

$('#mypress').keyup(function(){
  press = true;
});

$('#create').click(function(){
var myname= $('#myname').val();
var focus = $('#myfocus').is(':focus');    
var datasend = "myname="+ myname + "&focu=" + focus + "&pres=" + press;
        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'save.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg){
                // print result
                            alert('success');
            }
            });
    })
```

This will send the parameters as true or false in your query string, but the larger question is what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  The keyup event will fire for ANY key pressed and only if it's pressed while the element with the listener is focused.  In addition, why are you passing a query string as a request parameter for a POST request?  Query params are appended to the URL for GET requests, but for POST you can create an object with your data and assign it to the request body using the data property.  Unless you are trying to formulate some kind of other request with a literal query string.